# Transcendence basis for affine varieties

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

$X$ -- irreducible affine variety. $K[X]$ –its algebra of regular functions. Let $t_1, \ldots, t_d$ be a transcendence basis for $K[X]$. It is said that

1. Open dense set of $X$ can be defined precisely by $t_1, \ldots, t_d$.
2. Any point of $X$ is defined by $t_1, \ldots, t_d$ up to finite set.

As for part 2, it is clear, that every point of $X$ corresponds to homomorphism $\chi_{x}:K[X] \rightarrow K$, i.e. $I_{x}$ - maximal ideal of $K[X]$  ($J_x \subset I(X)$, where $I(X)$ - radical ideal of $X$. Since $\chi_{x}$ is defined by coordinate functions, which are algebraic over $K[t_1, \ldots, t_d]$ then for each coordinate of point $x$ we have only finitely many variants (as soltutions of polynomial of one variable).

As for part1, I think that it is more fruitful to think in terms of ideals, but my own thoughts are  quite  obscure.

So, I will appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @KReiser, why part 1 is actually true, and check my explanations for part 2